# Where is the CSV plug in controller?

Tags: grails

I am using the grails csv plugin 'org.grails.plugins:csv:1.0.1'.  It works great.  However, the plugin adds a test controller with an action in my project.
I can access the controller from this action. It generates a sample csv file. I am trying to delete this controller but I can't find it.  Where is it?  Thanks!

```
localhost:8080/csvTest/writeCsv
```

Comment: I have deleted my answer as based on the comments added to the answer it sounds like the actual question is something like can you delete a class that is in a `.jar` dependency that your application is pulling in.  The answer is "no".

Comment: You got it!  Thanks for explaining .